# Live console input/output for a gameserver using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, cmd, minecraft

**General information:** I have a Minecraft server running in the basement for some friends that is running for a couple months now. We were using TeamViewer to input commands into the console and view possible errors while the server was running. The console of a Minecraft server basically shows you a log of events with timestamps as well as a command input line at the bottom that enables you to execute in-game commands with administrator rights.

[image: example console output]

The console is started via a batch file:

```
:startup
@echo off
set v1=6
cls
Java -Xmx%v1%G -jar spigot.jar nogui
goto startup
```

The spigot.jar file is the file that basically runs the server.

Because we manage multiple servers and the TeamViewer process is quite insecure and slow, i wanted to find other ways to access the console.

**Target:** I want to create a HTML webinterface that uses JavaScript or PHP to communicate with the server console. It should be able to show the live console log as well as being able to type commands in the browser that are then executed in the commandline on the server.

**Problems:**

- Is there any way to send a JavaScript/PHP input to the console so that I can execute commands from a webinterface?
- Can I save the live console output to a .txt file that the JavaScript/PHP script can then display live on the webinterface?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals several attempts at this. https://www.mcmyadmin.com/ There are also various open source options. Have you looked into this? Would save reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend moving your setup outside of a Windows environment, as you're going to have a much easier time hosting a PHP server, etc. in a Linux environment.

Admittedly, I'm not familiar with MineCraft, but it looks like the batch file you have is effectively just launching a Java JAR which can be done from any computer with the JRE installed. Java console apps read input on the STDIN of a process and output on STDOUT for any application-generated output. This is incredibly easy to pickup in a Ubuntu environment.

For example, let's say you install the standard LAMP stack on a fresh Ubuntu install. You'll have PHP for running your server-side process, and Apache for hosting any web interface you decide to build. Keeping a focus on frontend vs. backend, I'd probably try to setup an API in PHP using Slim or another lightweight framework. In the API endpoint you use to start your server, it would look something like this:

```
exex('screen -d -m -S ServerOne');    
exec('screen -S ServerOne -p 0 -X stuff "java -Xmx%v1%G -jar spigot.jar nogui > /some_path_to_log^M"');
```

The first `exec()` will create a screen session named "ServerOne" inside of which your server process can run. The second `exec()` will send the command needed to start your server process inside of the screen session. Effectively, this will run your server asynchronously to your PHP script and write the output to the specified path. Knowing where to expect the output, in the API endpoint you use to get your log, you'd have something like:

```
$logContent = file_get_content('/some_path_to_log');
```

Finally, in the API endpoint you use to write commands to your server, you would have something that looks like:

```
exec('screen -S ServerOne -p 0 -X stuff "<your_command_here>^M"');
```

This will write to the STDIN stream of your server's Java process which should, in turn, be interpreted as if you were actually typing at the keyboard of the console itself.

That's the basics of it, or at least where I'd get started. There are some pretty cool things that you could do with WebSockets to open a live I/O session for your server's console, but it'd be a bit more involved than this post. If you're interested, check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) for PHP or [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) for Node.js.

Consider [this ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi/547144) for more information on sending input to screen sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could show the log on a website like this:

first gameserver script:

```
:startup
@echo off
set v1=6
cls
Java -Xmx%v1%G -jar spigot.jar nogui > log.txt
fileup log.txt
goto startup
```

second gameserver script(called fileup.bat){replace myusername, mypassword and servername.com with the credentials if your php server}:

```
@echo off
echo user MyUserName> ftpcmd.dat
echo MyPassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat SERVERNAME.COM
del ftpcmd.dat
```

php-server side script:

```
<?php
$filename = "log.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");

$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
fclose($fp);
print_r($lines);
?>
```

by the way: I have not tested any of these scripts and they might not work, I just based this on my knowledge of php and batch. Also, the second batch script needs to be in the same directory as the first batch script and you do not have to run the second batch script

Note:
I am an experienced PHP user but I do not know very much about batch(I use linux) but I suppose this will work and I have used batch very often in the past. Also I recommend using the PHP script on an external hosted php server from 000webhost.com or infinityfree.net because they are free and save you a lot of time + they have all the needed ftp things preconfigured.

Please let me know if this worked